# How to reset a custom theme

Tags: themes, admin

After making a lot of little changes to the current custom theme  [[zeeBizzCard]](http://themezee.com/zeebizzcard/) I'm using, I want to reset it back to it's original style. Being new to WP, I didn't make a backup of the default theme and can not find a quick and easy method of reseting the theme.

Have I missed something, or is there no "reset" options for downloaded themes?

Thanks

Comment: Why not simply download it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look into the file [`includes/admin/theme-admin.php`](http://themes.svn.wordpress.org/zeebizzcard/1.1/includes/admin/theme-admin.php) you’ll see that the theme’s options are stored in `'themezee_options'`. You can either delete these options per database manager or per a plugin.

If you aren’t familiar with database operations, copy the following code into a PHP file, install it as plugin and activate it once. Then deactivate it immediately.

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: Reset zeeBizzCard options
 */

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'reset_zeebizzcard_options' );

function reset_zeebizzcard_options()
{
    delete_option( 'themezee_options' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your easiest option to 'reset the theme' would be to select another theme in the admin section then delete the zeebizz theme and download it again.

Comment: Will that delete the saved options? I am not familiar with this specific theme.